# IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0. Cant figure it out

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have the following code:

```
preds = np.reshape(preds, (preds.shape[0]))
for index in range(0, len(preds)):
    pred = (preds[index]+1)* (X_test[index][0]) #error on this line
    preds_original.append(pred)
preds_original = np.array(preds_original)
if train_phase:
    return [date, y_test, preds_original]
else:
    import datetime
    return [date+datetime.timedelta(days=1),y_test]
```

But I am getting this error:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what does preds looks like? and X_test also?

Comment: X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

Comment: preds = np.reshape(preds, (preds.shape[0]))

Comment: I am asking about how the data looks like or if you could paste output of preds.shape and X_test.shape before the first line, then it would be good to debug.

Comment: X_train, y_train = train[:row,:-1], train[:row,-1]
    X_test, y_test = price_matrix[row:,:-1], price_matrix[row:,-1]
    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

Comment: date = data.index[row+9:]
    date = np.reshape(date, (date.shape[0]))
    X_test = price_matrix[row:,:-1]
    y_test = price_matrix[row:,:-1]
    preds_original = []
    preds = np.reshape(preds, (preds.shape[0]))

Comment: Look at your comments!  Can you read that code?  I can't.  We need to see the `shape` and `dtype` of the relevant arrays.  Specifically `preds` and `Xtest`. One of those has a size 0 dimension. You/we need to figure of which.  Then we can worry about the why.